# How to get file name by its unique id?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I have unique id of a MSword file.I want to know the name of this word file and location,where this file is stored by this unique id.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the "unique id" and where did you get it from?

Comment: where did u get this unique id?

Comment: i found this id by code........

Comment: What kind of code? A VSTO Word Add-In? Open XML SDK? A web application with a database? If you can't give us details, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be a query in the database you got the ID from: `SELECT path FROM documents WHERE id = @whatever`

(btw, I also voted to close as "Not a real question")

Comment: I think I missed the patch where a SQL engine was integrated into Word... but considering the question... I'm up voting this.